# Choosing PLL Loop Filter Bandwidth and Phase Margin for Frequency Ramp Generation

Tags: filter, pll

I am new to PLLs and am trying to use one to generate a frequency ramp between 5.725 GHz and 5.875 GHz. I have found tools online that help design loop filters for PLLs, and all of these tools require that the user know the desired loop filter bandwidth and phase margin. I have not been able to find suggestions for choosing filter bandwidth. Also, I understand that filter bandwidth and phase margin are related, but I don't know how to choose appropriate values for them for this application.

Comment: What experiences and skill sets do you bring to the table, regarding nearly \$6\:\text{GHz}\$ signals? (You may want to include some discussion of the reason why you need this and some of your thoughts.)

Comment: Can you  define slew rate MHz/ms tracking rate or capture time or LPF BW of clock noise or BW output of signal and BW of noise, then any performance features you expect? Anything?

Comment: I am a total beginner with PLLs, so no. PLL is for FMCW radar. Specifically, I am trying to understand a project I found online. Unsure of how designer made decisions like this one. In most sources I have found nebulous recommendations for choosing bandwidth like "increase loop bandwidth for more rapid loop response."

Comment: I understand you need to read more to ask a better question.   Use the key words like this.   https://scholar.google.ca/scholar?q=fmcw+radar+pll&hl=en&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart. Then when U hit a paywall, search the title.. try again... https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Frank_Herzel/publication/235919813_Phase_noise_modeling_for_integrated_PLLs_in_FMCW_radar/links/09e415142eb153c696000000/Phase-noise-modeling-for-integrated-PLLs-in-FMCW-radar.pdf

Comment: to achieve a clean phase trajectory, you may need a higher-order loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A PLL uses integration to eliminate steady state phase error in a stable input.   Whereas with a ramp f input, there is a gain-dependant fixed phase-error ( as well as other variables)

Not having done FMCW RADAR before, may I refer to an excellent article.

It defines all the variables that affect BW , settling time and fixed phase error which is an indicator of Spectral Density noise BW that contributes (error and ) has both 1st and 2nd order sensitivity.

https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Frank_Herzel/publication/235919813_Phase_noise_modeling_for_integrated_PLLs_in_FMCW_radar/links/09e415142eb153c696000000/Phase-noise-modeling-for-integrated-PLLs-in-FMCW-radar.pdf

If the link does not work , search..

Phase Noise Modeling for Integrated PLLs in
FMCW Radar

Frank Herzel, Arzu Ergintav, and Yaoming Sun